# Extracting phone numbers from websites

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract phone numbers using regex.I already checked previous answers but they are not working with me.

I tried with different regex as mentioned but non works with acutal number, rather it gives other IDs as numbers.

```
def getPhone(self, text):
    mobile = re.findall(r'(?:\+?\d{2}[ -]?)?\d{10}', text)
    # mobile = re.findall(r'\+[-()\s\d]+?(?=\s*[+<])', text)
    # mobile = re.findall(r'/\(([0-9]{3})\)([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3})([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\5([0-9]{4})/', text)
    # mobile = re.findall(r'\+[-()\s\d]+?(?=\s*[+<])', text)
    return mobile
```

I want to catch followign numbers (sample text- https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5ddc24d3e5a910b92d18fe78fdb32852)

```
(510) 588-3915
+1 (510) 879-4700
+1(888)654-0143
+1(919)277-2172
+1(866)707-7709
+1(919)597-7014
+44 (0) 20 8435 6555
+44 (0) 20 8435 6555
+33 1 70 70 96 61
+41 (44) 595 94 01
+32 (9) 277 94 21
+34 (0) 931 790 659
045 4750666
+41 44 595 94 01
+31 (0) 20 262 3824
+31 478-511014
+32 9 277 94 21
+91 900 133 5555
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Show us how `text` looks like

Comment: Show the HTML please

Comment: Are you familiar with RegExLib.com? They have a pretty extensive list of phone number regexes: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone%20number&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: If you have a help-desk regex problem, look for existing solutions to problems and modify as needed.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar: I have updated, please check the text

Comment: This regex worked for your examples: `\+?(\d*)\s?\(?(\d*)\)?\s?(\d*)[\s-]?(\d*)\s?(\d*)\s?(\d*)\s?`, in case you are still interested. It might be a good idea to write a couple of regexes instead of one that is huge and might overmatch. Say, one regex for regular lanline numbers and one for cell phone numbers.

Comment: @honeyboney When working with HTML try and avoid regex. BeautifulSoup is a great library to use in this case.
 ```def getPhone(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

    tags = soup.findAll("td", {"align": "center", "width": "25%", "valign": "top"})

    return [tag.string for tag in tags if tag.string is not ""]```

Comment: [`^(?:\+?\d+ ?)?(?:\(\d+\) ?)?(?:\d+[ -]){0,4}\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/PCeGS3/1)?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel: I tried it but it gives empty result  like `(u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u''), (u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u''), (u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'')` can you please help a bit more

Comment: @honeyboney I just noticed that I used the wrong text sample - I tried to match the list of numbers, not the html glob. So I guess it would need a little more work.